# Division and Power in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to divide a variable by 100 and power it.

```
  var a = 1;

  var b = (a / 100) ^ 2;
```

The value in 'b' becomes 2 when it should be 0.01 ^ 2 = 0.0001.

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is not the exponent operator. It's the bitwise XOR operator. To apply a power to a number, use `Math.pow()`:

```
var b = Math.pow(a / 100, 2);
```

As to why you get `2` as the result when you use `^`, bitwise operators compare the individual bits of two numbers to produce a result. This first involves converting both operands to integers by removing the fractional part. Converting `0.01` to an integer produces `0`, so you get:

```
00000000 XOR 00000010   (0 ^ 2)
00000010                (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
2 ^ 10
```

It gives you `8`. This is easily explained: JS does not have a power operator, but a XOR: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

You are looking for `Math.pow` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow))

Answer (score 0):

Power in javasript is made with Math.pow(x, y) function, not typing ˆ in between.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2021:**

Exponentiation operator is available since [ECMAScript 2016](https://262.ecma-international.org/7.0/#sec-exp-operator).

So, you can do something like:

```js
var b = (a / 100) ** 2;
```